# printf crashes after successful printing

Tags: c, netbeans, printf, printf-debugging

Language is C. I have an array of char* types (char *array[] / char** array) as function argument, and I want to print them all to separate lines like this:

```
    while (*array) {

      printf("%s\n", *array);
      printf("after last print");
      array++;
    }
```

Now for some reason, with a certain input, it manages to print all the values, but immediately crashes after the last *array is printed. So after the last printf, it doesn't print the "after last print" anymore. Unfortunately, I'm on Windows 7 with netbeans C support, without gdb. There were some problems when I tried to install it to netbeans, but that's another story.

First of all, what could be causing this? Secondly, how could I without gdb try to debug this behaviour best? If one provides an answer that helps me to debug the problem and that way solve it, I will grant points from that alone too. Some background information related to the function argument that causes the crash: I used strtok to generate char** arr from char* string, where a space was used as the delimeter.

EDIT:

Some more information: If I inside that same function try to printf the last *array, it works fine, and the program continues normally. So this works:

```
printf("%s\n", array[4]);
```

The last index before NULL happens to be 4 in my test case. But then when that same thing is done inside the loop like seen before, it does manage to printf it, but crashes right away after, not printing the second line anymore.

Comment: It's likely that last array element is not set with `NULL` pointer. You would need something like `array[n] = NULL;`, where `n` is the number of strings. Of course, the`array` would need a room for `n+1` elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't explicitly initialize the last element of your string array to be null, it's going to be an uninitialized (i.e. *wild* pointer), so when you dereference it in `printf` it will crash.

Things to do:

1. Explicitly initialize the last element of your string array to be NULL so that the loop will actually know to stop at the end.
2. Instead of incrementing the pointer, increment the offset at which you dereference it with a loop counter variable.

This code works just fine for me and doesn't crash:

```
#include <stdio.h>
char *array[] = { "Hello", "World", "My", "Name", "Is", "Govind", "Parmar", NULL } ;

int main()
{   
    int i;
    for(i = 0; *(array+i); i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", *(array+i));
    }
    printf("after last print\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tested and the last is NULL, and still it crashes right after it manages to printf the last *array, but doesn't print the last 'after last print' anymore =/.

Comment: Using your code I was able to get the program to a state where it does printf the after last print, before crashing. It crashes to memory free functions afterwards. What I don't understand why it didn't printf it in my version of the code, even it clearly crashes to code that comes after the function. But your code did it somehow, so I'll grant you the correct answer.

Comment: @VilleMiekk-oja crashing on calls to `free` or `operator delete` is a sign of poor memory management elsewhere in your code

Comment: Yes, though it's not my code. I'm doing an online course where in this situation they handle the freeing part after I make this function. My guess is, that the strtok function I used to generate the char* array, does something to the array that it can't be free'd in a way this course is trying to. I guess they wouldn't have wanted me to go with the strtok shortcut for this :D

Comment: @VilleMiekk-oja `strtok` *will* modify the string pointer it is passed

Comment: Yes, and I'm generating the char* array inside a while loop like this: arr[i] = token; Maybe that somehow also puts the array itself into a state where it cannot be free'd the way it is tried to free.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115663/discussion-between-govind-parmar-and-ville-miekk-oja).

Answer (score 0):

I commented out code that comes after the use of this function. This resulted into fully successful run of the code. So apparently, the execution order of the code wasn't linear in a way that it would execute line after line. But after the last *array print it tried to execute code that was coming after the function. Now when I commented out that code, the function works like a charm.

Those who are interested, the code I commented out related to freeing memory from the *arrays.